How to setup advance installer with ungoogled-chromium-windows exe file same as like google chrome
I have completed build with ungoogled-chromium-windows and now, Need to change app icon https://prnt.sc/8tjSIuDiDtNY and also implement Advance installer like google chrome and wave browser.
Please help me how can i proceed?
Thanks
